# Creating a new VS extension solution is not working even if I copy code from a working solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, vsix, vs-extensibility

I am trying to create one vs extension for teamexplorer. I have found some clue the following link https://hamidshahid.blogspot.com/2017/09/extending-team-explorer-in-vs2017.html

However if I download the same project and try to run it is working but if I try to make a new solution on my own then it is not working. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have compared the files and references also. But I am not finding any difference.

Has anyone faced such issues ? If so can anyone help me how to deal with such situation.

Comment: Pretty difficult to "guess" without you posting the pertinent project file or code for review. Have you tried creating a stock .VSIX project and then compare the .csproj that was generated with yours?

Comment: When you try to run it, what error you actually. You at least should have specified this. Other than that, it is difficult to identify your problem.

Comment: I am not getting any error. The new option is not displayed in team explorer when I run.I have compared both the files My version of code can be found at [here](https://github.com/ramsankar184/TeamExplorerExtensionVS2019)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.
To extend Team Explorer, the key thing to remember is to add the assembly containing classes that implement Team Explorer interfaces as a MEF component. This will ensure that visual studio loads it up when loading team explorer.

So when I added the project type as MefComponent in assets tab of the .manifest file my project worked.